# NHibernate (c#.net) - automatically map results of a SQLQuery to a dto object

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Up to now (with NHibernate) I've used entity mapping and not really got involved with creating raw sql queries - but somethings come up where I need to do exactly that.

The problem I have is I want to automatically map the columns aliases of my query to a Dto object.

This works, but i have to specify the column alias' in the order of the query.

SQL

```
string sql = "select mycol1 as ColumnOne from mytable";
```

NHibernate Query

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
            .AddScalar("ColumnOne", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
            .SetResultTransformer(
                  NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean<MyDtoObject>()
            );
```

MyDtoObject

```
 public class MyDtoObject 
 {
     public int ColumnOne {get;set;}
 }
```

But is there a way to making NHibernate automate the mapping between the columns in the query and the Dto without creating a mapping class?

I've seen some examples of using aliases in the query e.g.

```
string sql = "select mycol1 as {ColumnOne} as ColumnOne from mytable"; /// ???
```

But cannot get this to work as the alias {ColumnOne} appear not to be replaced before being sent to the db as a sql statement.

Any idea?

TIA

Sam

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after here - are you trying to make NHibernate guess that the DB column "mycol1" should end up in ColumnOne in the DTO without explicitly telling it to? I don't see how that would be possible.

Comment: no, only use the alias to map the the poco object. i've actually sussed out by putting double quotes round the alias actually maps it correctly. `select col1 "ColumnOne" from mytable` works, the problem i'm dealing with now is that an integer in the db is being returned as a decimal which raises an exception when being assigned to the int property of the "MyDtoObject". The type System.Decimal can not be assigned to a property of type System.Int32

Comment: presumably because the backend db is oracle and the type is a number(0dp). is there any way of casting all types of x to system type of y?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe System.Linq.Dymanic will help:

```
use System.Linq.Dynamic;

string ColumnAlisName = "ColumnOne";
var query = mytable.Select(String.Format("new (mycol1 as {0})",ColumnAlisName));
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i really don't know how that helps? you know i'm trying to automap the column aliases of a NHibernate SQLQuery to a unmapped POCO object?